# How get event when text control loses focus?

Tags: text, focus, javafx-2

I have JavaFX 2 app, and I need to perform some actions when TextField loses focus. But I do not see any events happening on the node when it loses focus.

Is it possible to somehow listen for focus lose event on TextField?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Add a ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener%28javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener%29) to the TextField's [focusedProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty%28%29).

Comment: Oh, stupid me :) I was fiddling with `addEventFilter` and completely forgot that I can use change listeners on properties. Thank you!